# how to check if the date picked from a datetimepicker is the same as the date in a sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

How can I check the date I pick from a `DateTimePicker` control exists in a SQL table?

I have a `DateTimePicker` on my ASP.NET page where I can select a date. I need to check if this selected date exists in a SQL table (in a table called `blockdate`). If the selected date does exist, I need to enter the corresponding values from the `date` and `reason` columns in the `blockdate` table into a `DataGridView`.

Can anybody tell me how I can do this?

This is the code I have so far to check if the selected date is a weekend.

```
DatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime date = DatePicker.SelectedDate.Date;
DateTime weekend;

if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    weekend = date.AddDays(+2);
}

if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    weekend = date.AddDays(+1);
}
else
{
    weekend = date;
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that holds dates in your `blockdate` table? Are you only looking to compare the date part (day, month and year)? What about times (your SQL column might have these)?

Comment: @Bridge : blockdate has the datatype of date, and reson the datatype nvarchar(100). I have already tried to get the selected date and try to check if the selected date is a weekend. if so, it should add +1 or +2 to get the next monday. but now i need to check if the selected dat is a block date? here is my code so far. i put up the code i have in my original post.

Comment: @user1782391 Which RBDMS are you using? SQL Server? Mysql? Oracle?

Comment: i have a SQL express database.

Comment: @user1782391: Are you storing a `datetime` value in database?

Comment: @huMpty duMpty : i am storing a date value in a sql express 2008 database, using visual web developer 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think calling the database on every time when the `DatePicker` values change not going to be an ideal solution.

You can select all the dates from you sql table to a list in pageload.

```
var dateList = new List<DateTime>();
dateList = //all the dates from you sql table
```

Then when the `DatePicker` value changed, you can match the value against your list.

Hope this helps